# Get index of max of Spark Dataframe with Sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, apache-spark-sql, sparklyr

I'm trying to get the index of the max values in a row from a Spark dataframe. It's straight forward to get the maximum value. I do the following:

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)

config <- spark_config()
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", config = config)

df <- replicate(n = 3, sample(x = 0:10,size = 10, rep=TRUE)) %>%
  as.data.frame()


sdf <- sdf_copy_to(sc, df, overwrite = T)

sdf %>% spark_apply(
  function(df) {
    return( pmax(df[1], df[2], df[3]) )})
```

I've tried to collect these into a vector using `ft_vector_assembler` but I am not familiar with the returning data structure. For example, I cannot  recover max from the following code

```
sdf %>% ft_vector_assembler(
  input_cols = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), 
  output_col = "features") %>%
  select(features) %>%
  spark_apply( function(df) pmax(df))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with your first problem:

> It's straight forward to get the maximum value.

It indeed is, however `spark_apply` is just not a way to go. Instead it is better to use `greatest` function:

```
sdf %>% mutate(max = greatest(V1, V2, V3))
```

The same function can be used for you second problem, however due to `sparklyr` limitations, you'll have to use SQL expression directly:

```
expr <- c("V1", "V2", "V3") %>% 
  paste0(
    "CAST(STRUCT(`",
    ., "`, ", seq_along(.),
    ") AS struct<value: double, index: double>)", collapse=", ")  %>% 
  paste0("greatest(", ., ").index AS max_index")

sdf %>% 
  spark_dataframe() %>%
  invoke("selectExpr", list("*", expr)) %>%
  sdf_register()
```

In Spark 2.4 (as for now unsupported in `sparklyr`) it *might be* possible to

```
sdf %>% mutate(max
  max_index = array_max(arrays_zip(array(V1, V2, V3), array(1, 2, 3))).1
)
```